# Loop in R duplicates columns in weighted average calculations

Tags: r, split, weighted-average

I've got a list of 137 xts objects, each with 4 variables. Each element is a daily series split by months.

Example code:

```
recession <- sample(1:100, 4169, replace = TRUE)
unemployed <- sample(1:100, 4169, replace = TRUE)
jobs <- sample(1:100, 4169, replace = TRUE)
insurance <- sample(1:100, 4169, replace = TRUE)
# sequence of daily dates from January 1st 2004 to May 31st 2015:
new1 <- seq(from=as.Date("2004-01-01"), to=as.Date("2015-05-31"), by = "day") 
daily_df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(new1), unemployed, jobs, recession, insurance)
library(xts)
daily_series <- xts(daily_df[-1], order.by = as.Date(new1))
# split daily series into monthly elements of daily data:
split_list <- split(daily_series, f = "months", drop = FALSE, k = 1)
```

What I want to do is calculate a weighted average across all the variables and elements of the list, so I ran the following code:

```
monthly_av = NULL
for (i in 1:length(split_list)) {
for (j in 1:ncol(split_list[[i]])) {
monthly_av = cbind(monthly_av, xts(weighted.mean(split_list[[i]][,j]), order.by = index(split_list[[i]][1])))
}}
```

However, the output it gives me is this:

[image]

My desired output is to be an xts object with 137 rows and 4 columns corresponding to the 4 variables. I can't figure out why this is occurring - have I misspecified the loop or is it the `cbind` function that's doing it?

Comment: Your weighted mean doesn't have any weights does it?

Comment: I think you should also set `monthly_av` as matrix-like object, and then fill it by row/col index if you want to do it this way `monthly_av = matrix(NA,nrow=i,ncol=j)` and then `monthly_av[i,j] = ....`

Comment: @thelatemail No it doesn't, its set to default.

Comment: @thelatemail: Would I set the matrix-like object in the loop, or before it? Given that you specified the rows and columns as i and j.

Comment: @thelatemail: It doesn't seem to work. It gives me the following error: 
`Error in monthly_av[i, j] = cbind(monthly_av, xts(weighted.mean(split_list[[i]][,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: It does work - `monthly_av = matrix(NA,nrow=i,ncol=j)` and then replace your line with: `monthly_av[i,j] = xts(weighted.mean(split_list[[i]][,j]), order.by = index(split_list[[i]][1]))` - Though I'm sure there is a better way than looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to generate a table with monthly weighted average data:

```
data <- do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(1:length(split_list)
               , function(x) apply(split_list[[x]], 2, weighted.mean)))

> dim(data)
[1] 137   4
```

And this will mantain an xts object:

```
data_xts <- do.call(cbind, lapply(1:4, function(x) 
  apply.monthly(daily_series[,x],weighted.mean)))
```

And using a `for` loop:

```
monthly_av = NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(daily_series)){
  monthly_av <- cbind(monthly_av, apply.monthly(daily_series_ts[,i],weighted.mean))
}
```

Comment: I'd much rather use for loops. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Not sure that I can do it in efficient way but I will try

Comment: Still seems to calculate the monthly averages by assuming a stock variable, whilst my variables are flow. Thanks anyway for the try.

Comment: I quite missunderstand you. Is that not a desired output?

Comment: Ok, glad to help you!